# vector fields and closed curves.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The vector field $\vec F(\vec R)$ is defined by

$$\vec F(\vec R) = \oint_C \|\vec r − \vec R\|^2 d\vec r$$

where $\vec r$ lies on the simple closed curve $C$. Show that there are constant vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ such that $\vec F(\vec R) = \vec R \times \vec A + \vec B$. Deduce that $\nabla\times \vec F = -4\iint_S d\vec S $, Where $S$ is any smooth surface spanning $C$.

Comment: What do you mean by smooth surface spanning $C$?

Comment: @EnjoysMath A surface $S$ whose bounding curve is $C$: $\partial S = C$.

Comment: Duplicate answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724459/line-integrals-cross-products-surface-integrals-and-stokes-theorem-related-pr

Somehow I can't flag it because it doesn't find this thread.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part,

$$\vec F(\vec R) = \oint_{\partial S} \|\vec r − \vec R\|^2 d\vec\ell\\
=\iint_Sd\vec a\times\nabla\left(\|\vec r − \vec R\|^2\right)\\
=\iint_Sd\vec a\times\left(2(\vec r - \vec R)\right)\\
=2\iint_Sd\vec a\times\left(\vec r - \vec R\right)\\
=2\iint_Sd\vec a\times\vec r -2\iint_Sd\vec a\times\vec R\\
=2\iint_Sd\vec a\times\vec r+2\vec R\times\iint_Sd\vec a\\
=\vec R \times \vec A + \vec B,$$

where $\vec A := 2\iint_Sd\vec a$ and $\vec B := 2\iint_Sd\vec a\times\vec r$.

For the second part,

$$\nabla\times\vec F = \nabla\times\left(\vec R \times \vec A + \vec B\right)\\
=\nabla\times\left(\vec R \times \vec A\right)\\
=-\vec A(\nabla\cdot\vec R)+(\vec A \cdot \nabla)\vec R\\
=3\vec A + \vec A\\
=-2\vec A\\
=-4\iint_Sd\vec a.$$

---

Notes:

$$\nabla\left(\|\vec r − \vec R\|^2\right)=2((\vec r - \vec R)\cdot\nabla)(\vec r - \vec R)=2(\vec r - \vec R)$$